# I want use jQuery to get my Column Heading in a Datagrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, web

want to get the header text of the the column I click on.
The following gets the cell data from the row and column that the click occurs:

```
if ($(this).index() == 3) {
    var row2 = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var Col3 = row2.children("td:eq(3)").text();
    alert(Col3); 
}
```

I need the column title instead.

Thanks

Here is the Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GV_Tab1" 
               class= "GV_card"
               AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="HeaderCss2" 
               runat="server" 
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="GV_Scorecard_Tab1_SelectedIndexChanged"
               OnRowDataBound="GV_Tab1_RowDataBound"
               >
      <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Col" 
                    runat="server"
                    commandargument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex%>' 
                    ItemStyle-Width="54" 
                    ItemStyle-Height="20px" 
                  > </asp:Label> 
             </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="secure 1" headertext="secure 1" ItemStyle-Width="220px" ItemStyle-Height="20px"   />
           <asp:boundfield datafield="secure 2" headertext="secure 2" ItemStyle-Width="140px" ItemStyle-Height="20px" />
           <asp:boundfield datafield="aDays"  DataFormatString="{0:n0}" headertext="0-30 Days" visible='true' ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="bDays"  DataFormatString="{0:n0}" headertext="31HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="fDays"  DataFormatString="{0:n0}" headertext="151-180 Days" visible='true' ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="gDays"  DataFormatString="{0:n0}" headertext="180+ Days" visible='true' ItemStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:boundfield datafield="Total"  DataFormatString="{0:n0}" headertext="Grand Total" ItemStyle-Width="65px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="ColumnRef" 
                    runat="server"
                    commandargument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex%>' 
                    ItemStyle-Width="54" 
                    ItemStyle-Height="20px" 
                  > </asp:Label> 
            </ItemTemplate>  
           </asp:TemplateField>     

         </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Here is event code:
      $(document).ready(function() {

```
      if ($("#<%=GV_Tab1.UniqueID%> th") != "Column Title") {
          $("#<%=GV_Tab1.UniqueID%> td").click(function() {
```

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div id="GV_Tab1-divid" >
 <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="GV_Scorecard" border="1" id="GV_Scorecard_Tab1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="HeaderCss2">
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">secure 1</th><th scope="col">secure 1</th><th scope="col">0-30 Days</th><th scope="col">31-60 Days</th><th scope="col">61-90 Days</th><th scope="col">91-120 Days</th><th scope="col">121-150 Days</th><th scope="col">151-180 Days</th><th scope="col">180+ Days</th><th scope="col">Grand Total</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td onClientClick="alert('Cell 0 Clicked');" style="background-color:#F5DCBE;">
                  <span id="GV_Tab1_ctl02_Col" ItemStyle-Width="54" ItemStyle-Height="20px" commandargument="0"></span> 
             </td><td style="background-color:#F5DCBE;height:20px;width:220px;">
```

Comment: What does the html look like?   What event is that code running on?

Comment: The reason I am doing this my Gridview collapses and expands causing the program to lose title relationship.

Comment: Here is the markup of the Gridview:

Comment: That's just a chunk of it. And clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your  ?

then change

```
row2.children("td:eq(3)").text()
```

to

```
row2.children("td:eq(3)").prop("title") //attr if you are using jquery < 1.7
```

Comment: he asked for the header: which is in the thead / tr / 3rd th

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast replies - unfortuntatle nothing is working yet.  I am playing with the answers sent.

Answer (score 0):

nice question :

http://jsbin.com/ecibuw/3/edit

```
var i=-1;
$("td").click (function (){

  i=$(this).parent("tr").find("td").index($(this));

    alert( $(this).parents("table").find("tr td").eq(i).text());

});
```

Comment: This one is getting me my top row data, not the heading.

Comment: @user977645 If my answer was helpful - you are welcome to check it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the index of the element within the row. After that go to the thead and get the child with that index.

```
$('td').click(function()
{
    var index= $(this).parent().children().index(this);
    var val = $(this).parents('table:first').find('thead th').eq(index).text();
    alert(val);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5jJA/)

Comment: Would you elaborate this? Or edit my fiddle. Because I don't get it.

Comment: I tried to change the table to Gridview on fiddle. I put it in next message.  I am trying read the the Gridview coulmn heading when I click on any cell in the column.

Comment: Wait a bit. Gridwiew is a server side control which becomes other HTML elements on the client side. That's because the browser doesn't understand ASP it only understands HTML. Look at your page's source code. No Gridview there. So you cant use Gridwiew in JSFiddle.

Comment: I understand now about Fiddle. Do you need to see the HTML markup of the Gridview? I am able read anything I want with jQuery - except the headertext or <th scope("col")>

Comment: Yeah, the HTML markup would help a lot to help you :). Edit your original post and replace the Gridview with the HTML. Being a JQuery question that information is much more relevant. Thanks.